# W: GPG error:...InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available

Tags: debian, apt

**2021 edit**: think an eventual reinstall of OS sorted it. Note the private repositories were also added (via `apt-key`) in a now-deprecated way.
See:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1307181
- https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/apt-key-is-deprecated-how-to-add.html

---

Related:

- http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=134409
- [Debian stretch package system breaks when non-free added](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379344/debian-stretch-package-system-breaks-when-non-free-added)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387054/47501

After updating to debian buster, I've had trouble installing programs from 3rd party repositories (eg  [spotify](https://www.spotify.com/es/download/linux/), [seadrive](https://github.com/haiwen/seafile-user-manual/blob/master/en/desktop/install-on-linux.md#wiki-debian) (for seafile), [mono,](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin-debian) [mopidy](https://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/debian/)). Excerpt from `apt-get update`:

```
W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 13B00F1FD2C19886
E: The repository 'http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
```

I understand it has to do with how `apt` handles keys, namely "`preference for SHA-1 encryption has been turned off in APT`".

Relevant `apt-key list` excerpt for spotify:

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/spotify-2015-05-28-D2C19886.gpg     
------------------------------------------------------     
pub   rsa4096 2015-05-28 [SC] [expires: 2017-11-22]        
      BBEB DCB3 18AD 50EC 6865  0906 13B0 0F1F D2C1 9886   
uid           [ unknown] Spotify Public Repository Signing Key <operations@spotify.com>
```

`apt-get update` output: https://pastebin.com/sHFxAFvj

What do? Open tickets with the providers and for so long install with `--allow-unauthenticated`?

Note: this is not reproducing in a system that was dist-upgraded from stretch to buster.