# Renaming trusted.gpg to trusted.gpg-broken

Tags: debian, apt, gpg

I ran a fresh install of Debian stretch 9.8.0 and all was well. I then ran

```
sudo apt update
```

and I get an output which hits the ftp.debian.stretch server for the update thing is it tells me

```
unable to retrieve update trusted.gpg keys unauthorised
```

So I do a bit of research and came across a post, it said

> Rename `trusted.gpg` to `trusted.gpg-broken`

And now I can `sudo apt update` and basically get what ever I want as standard, but I don’t understand why after a fresh install the trusted keys were not found in the file?

And I also don’t understand what changing `trusted.gpg` to `trusted.gpg-broken` actually did to the keys.

Comment: [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379344/debian-stretch-package-system-breaks-when-non-free-added)?

Comment: That’s the one I followed to get it working, but I want info on why this fixes it and what does -broken acctually do? Nice1 Rovo

Comment: `-broken` doesn't mean anything. You can call it `-backup` or simply delete it to have the same effect. Renaming the file is just to get the old one out of the way but don't delete it for backup reasons. I think when the file is missing, `apt` will somehow regenerate (and thus fix) it. Why it happens in the first place, I don't know.

Comment: Sweet so just the renaming of it basically. When apt looks for the keys can not locate the directory so bypass that step I take it.